# Extract an RT_RCDATA section from a Win32 executable (preferably in C#)?

Tags: c#, winapi, resources, pinvoke

How do you extract an RT_RCDATA section from a Win32 executable (preferably in C#)?

The only way I know how to do this currently is opening up the EXE in Visual Studio.  I'd love to be able to do this entirely in C# if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P/Invoke LoadResource will be your safest bet.

Otherwise you'll have to write your own [P/E](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable_Format) processor eg. [PE Processor example](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Architecture/Retrieve-Resources-PE-II/).  The processor isn't the end of the world, but as you can see much more involved than a P/Invoke.

Almost forgot,as far as tools go, most P/E browsers will do this for you.  Eg. P/E Explorer, which is available but not really being developed.  I've also used IDA Pro for stuff like this.  A quick IDA plugin would do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to read a resource of type RCDATA from an executable (be aware that "executable section" means a different thing - it refers to the .text, .data, .rdata, etc parts of the PE file). If you want to read it from the current assembly, here is a tutorial showing how: [Accessing Embedded Resources using GetManifestResourceStream](http://www.attilan.com/2006/08/accessing-embedded-resources-u.php), using the [GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx) and [GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) methods.

If you don't want to read it from the current executable, you can use a method similar to the one shown [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1683.htm).

These methods have the advantage over PInvoke that they are 100% .NET and you don't have to fiddle with marshaling the arguments to/from platform data types and making sure that you validated all the return values.